# Spring pool connections with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, datasource, connection-pooling

I have (hypothetically) the following servers for my application; I work with MySQL.

1) Database used by the application (server located in Japan)
2) Database Backup (server located in Peru)
3) Emergency Database (server located in the U.S.)

I have a couple of questions about the capabilities of Spring:

A) How I can persist simultaneously in all datasources?

B) How I can create a connection pool in Spring so that if my first datasource does not respond, the system automatically works with the second datasource?

This is my actual `applicationContext-datasource.xml`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>META-INF/database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref local="dataSource"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Regards

Comment: You're going to be getting some serious latency no? One option is to define both datasources, and programatically check to see if the first is responding, and if not, use the second.

Comment: That's not the problems, its a academic project so the servers are near. The hibernate Stuff and my @Autowired Datasources dont have to know that the application is now working with other databse. Thats the  essence of conection pool rigth ?

Answer (score 0):

If I had the same problem I would try solve it outside of the application boundaries, so as not to have the application coupled with database topology .

I should request to persist an object to a logical entity perceived by Spring/Hibernate as a database and which is not part of the application, but it's aware of the database topology and availability, then delegate to it the distribution of the data.

Normally you can solve this through:

- [database replication feature](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)
- [clustering of databases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-cluster.html)